# Does the new site design have any easter eggs?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Easter egg is a jargon phrase from game developers. It is a small, usually hard to find detail or feature that is not documented anywhere except by people who have found it.

It would be neat it the site had a few.

Here's what some of them might be called:

- The gnostic page.
- The C.SE Codes.
- Jacob's ladder.

Comment: See also: [Site design: 404/captcha/error page images](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1730/site-design-404-captcha-error-page-images?cb=1).  (The first three links in that question might be of interest.)

Answer (score 5):

I hope we didn't wait that extra 6-8 weeks just so they could queue up an Easter Egg. Besides which date for Easter would they use?

Comment: Which date. That's funny.